# Не получается запустить тесты в режиме отладки C#

Tags: c#, отладка

[image: Скрин ошибки]

При запуске отладки выводится эта ошибка, .NET Core обновляла до 5.0, тесты в решение добавлены... Подскажите, пожалуйста, что можно сделать
5.0.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.402 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
You may only use the Microsoft .NET Core Debugger (vsdbg) with
Visual Studio Code, Visual Studio or Visual Studio for Mac software
to help you develop and test your applications.
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Целевой процесс завершил работу без вызова события, запущенного CoreCLR. Убедитесь, что в целевом процессе настроено использование .NET Core. Это может быть необходимо, если целевой процесс не запускался в .NET Core.
Программа "[424] QuadEqua.dll" завершилась с кодом -2147450749 (0x80008083).
```

Comment: А в чём была ошибка?

Comment: Её ещё не решили

Comment: При отладке чего? Какой проект? Какая у него целевая платформа? Какая у вас IDE? Почему у вас вообще 69 проблем пишет?

Comment: Пожалуйста, выполните команду `dotnet --list-sdks` и добавьте вывод в вопрос. Проблема скорее всего в том что сборка с тестами работает под той целевой платформой, которая у вас не установлена.

Comment: @bearpro Вывод: 5.0.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
5.0.402 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Отладка тестов. Требовалось написать набор модульных тестов для функции, решающей квадратное уравнение. IDE - VSCode. (net5.0)

Comment: В файле `.csproj` какая версия указана (`TargetFramework`)? И установлены ли все необходимые расширения для VS Code?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я же ответила, что net5.0. Устанавливала только этот пак: C# .Net Core Extension Pack (15 extensiones indispensables para programar con C# y .NET Core).